# Schedule pod on specific node without modifying PodSpec

Tags: kubernetes

As a k8s cluster administrator, I want to specify on which nodes (using labels) pods will be scheduled, but without modifying any PodSpec section.

So, nodeSelector, affinity and taints can't be options.
Is there any other solution ?

PS: the reason I can't modify the PodSpec is that deployed applications are available as Helm charts and I don't have hand on those files. Moreover, if I change the PodSpec, it will be lost on next release upgrade.

Comment: Does helm chart/template mean to be modified on the deployment using --value or --set, modifiers?
Why would upgrade be a problem if you can fire the same command (only change the version of the original chart to be upgraded)?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Otherwise I would have used the definition in a values.yaml. Thanks for your consideration on a two years old SO btw ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [PodNodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/admission-controllers/#podnodeselector) admission controller for this:

> This admission controller has the following behavior:
>
> 1. If the Namespace has an annotation with a key `scheduler.kubernetes.io/nodeSelector`, use its value as the node selector.
> 2. If the namespace lacks such an annotation, use the `clusterDefaultNodeSelector` defined in the PodNodeSelector plugin configuration file as the node selector.
> 3. Evaluate the pod’s node selector against the namespace node selector for conflicts. Conflicts result in rejection.
> 4. Evaluate the pod’s node selector against the namespace-specific whitelist defined the plugin configuration file. Conflicts result in rejection.

First of all you will need to [enable this admission controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/admission-controllers/#how-do-i-turn-on-an-admission-controller). The way to enable it depends on your environment, but it's done via the parameter `kube-apiserver --enable-admission-plugins=PodNodeSelector`.

Then create a namespace and annotate it with whatever node label you want all Pods in that namespace to have:

```
kubectl create ns node-selector-test
kubectl annotate ns node-selector-test \
    scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/node-selector=mynodelabel=mynodelabelvalue
```

To test it you could do something like this:

```
kubectl run busybox \
    -n node-selector-test -it --restart=Never --attach=false --image=busybox

kubectl get pod busybox -n node-selector-test -o yaml
```

It should output something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod 
metadata:
  name: busybox
  ....
spec:
  ...
  nodeSelector:
    mynodelabel: mynodelabelvalue
```

Now, unless that label exists on some nodes, this Pod will never be scheduled, so put this label on a node to see it scheduled:

```
kubectl label node myfavoritenode mynodelabel=mynodelabelvalue
```

Comment: How can it help him? Yes, he can use an admission controller, but the only result will be scheduling all pods in a namespace on selected nodes. He doesn't want to change specs and want to create new deployments it the Helm, but with your solution, he will need it anyway, at least for split all charts into different namespaces. But, if you anyway need to recreate releases, what is the reason to use the solution which can solve a problem only partially? Moreover, it will not help if you need to run pods on different nodes in one release.

Comment: I respectfully disagree, Anton. He can do `helm install --namespace=node-selector-test`, and that is much easier than changing all Pod templates.

Comment: But that command will create a new deployment and at least you will need to somehow manage 2 copies of application in the same time in 2 different namespaces. That can cause big problems. Moreover, if you anyway will create a new deployment, why do not use selectors in pods instead of admission controller?

Comment: Hi! Sorry for not being very active on my question. I like the way to use admission controllers over PodSpec as it decouples HOW a pod must run and WHERE it must run. 
But, your solution on namespace don't help me much as I deploy all my pods in default namespace (I use several GCP project and GKE clusters by environments).
Will try to search a node selector based on pods labels/annotations.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no other ways to specify on which nodes pod will be scheduled, only labels and selectors.

I think the problem with a Helm is related to that [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/issues/2735).

For now, the only way for you is to change a spec, remove release and deploy a new one with updated specs.

**UPD**

@Janos Lenart provides a way how to manage scheduling per-namespace. That is a good idea if your releases already are split among namespaces and if you don't want to spawn different pods on different nodes in a single release. Otherwise, you will have to create new releases in new namespaces and in that case I highly recommend you to use selectors in the Pods spec.